# Sublime Text python error

Tags: python, path, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've recently stared using sublime text for python and have a little problem. Whenever i try to run my program within sublime using CTRL+B. I get the following error:

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

I tried reinstalling python to C:\Python37-64 but the problem still persists.
Can anyone help?

Comment: add python to your environment variables.

Comment: Have you added python to PATH ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Add Python to your Windows Path
[Installing Python](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html)